# I can't iterate over line_styles (Matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib

Plot generates different colors for each lines but I also need to generate different line_styles for the graph. After searching for some information, I found itertools module. Yet I can't generate plot with the error: **There is no Line2D property "shape_list".**

```
import itertools
from glob import glob
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

shape_list = ["square", "triangle", "circle", "pentagon", "star", "octagon"]

# loop over all files in the current directory ending with .txt
for fname in glob("*.txt"):
    # read file, skip header (1 line) and unpack into 3 variables
    WL, ABS, T = np.genfromtxt(fname, skip_header=1, unpack=True)
    g = itertools.cycle(shape_list)
    plt.plot(WL, T, label=fname[0:3],shape_list = g.__next__())

plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
plt.xlim(200,1000)
plt.ylim(0,100)
plt.ylabel('Transmittance (%)')
mpl.rcParams.update({'font.size': 12})
plt.legend(loc=4,prop={'size':10})
plt.grid(True)
#plt.legend(loc='lower center')
plt.savefig('Transmittance', dpi=600)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The markers you can use with `plot` are defined [in the documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html)

to change the marker style, use the `marker=` argument to the call to `plot()`

eg:

```
plt.plot(WL, T, label=fname[0:3], marker=g.__next__())
```

**EDIT**

I'm putting in a full answer here to close that question

```
# list of symbols
shape_list = ["s", "^", "o", "*", "p", "h"]
g = itertools.cycle(shape_list) # so we can cycle through the list of symbols

# some fake data
x = np.linspace(200,1000,1000)
y = [x+100*b for b in range(6)]

# loop over files 
for i in range(6): # I'm simultating a loop here since I don't have any files
    # read file
    # do your plot
    # we use `g.next()` to get the next marker in the cycle
    # and `markevery` to only plot a few symbols so they dont overlap
    # adjust the value for your specific data
    plt.plot(x,y[i], marker=g.next(), markevery=100, label=i)

plt.xlabel('Wavelength (nm)')
plt.ylabel('Transmittance (%)')
plt.legend(loc=4,prop={'size':10})
plt.grid(True)
#plt.legend(loc='lower center')
#plt.savefig('Transmittance', dpi=600)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes. It works but lines are indistinguishable. It seems like they have a background and high frequency. It's hard to distinguish circle from square.

Comment: if you have so many markers that they become indistinguishable, you can use `markevery=` to only show one marker every x points. see http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/markevery_demo.html

Comment: Very useful comment. Thank you!

Comment: @esilik I've edited my answer to provide a full solution. Please accept one of the answer using the little check mark next to each answer (either of kameranis or mine) so that this question can be closed.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `g = itertools.cycle(shape_list)` should go outside the loop

Also see [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html#module-matplotlib.markers) for valid markers
What you probably want is

`plt.plot(WL, T, label=fname[0:3], marker = g.__next__())`

Comment: Yes. I've tried this just now but I've used linestyle instead of marker. I think there's a difference among them.

Comment: [http://nullege.com/codes/search/matplotlib.lines.Line2D.set_linestyle] (this is not what I'm looking for). I'm looking for [http://matplotlib.org/1.3.1/examples/pylab_examples/line_styles.html] (this).

Comment: `linestyle` is more general. I think you should use marker. You can do the same with `color` if you want more than the standard colors

Comment: In the link you posted, only the first three have a `linestyle`. For the rest, it is set to `None`

Comment: The problem is that the code doesn't provide me a good graph. Please look at the comparison of the images from this link: https://postimg.org/image/q5q1x4yox/. How can I improve it?

Comment: You don't want a marker there. You have too many points, therefore, skip the marker. What's wrong with the top image?

Comment: Maybe you can add some arrows to the spikes if they are relevant to what you want to stress about the graph

Comment: Top picture is very good but I will use it in my publication, so if they are going to print it colorless there will be no way to distinguish them. Moreover, I need to specify THE

Comment: Sample codes es1, es2.. with that line style or whatever  I will use for that.

Comment: You could play with `linewidth` as well with `linestyle`